# Unable to exceute Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

I am getting following error when trying to execute jenkins:

```
Oct. 28, 2018 6:07:25 P.M. Main main
SEVERE: Running with Java class version 55.0, but 52.0 is required.Run 
with the --enable-future-java flag to enable such behavior. See 
https://jenkins.io/redirect/java-support/
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 55.0
at Main.main(Main.java:139)

Jenkins requires Java 8, but you are running 11+28 from 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 55.0
at Main.main(Main.java:139)
```

Comment: It **literally** says exactly what to do to solve the problem in the error message. Did you read it?

Comment: Jenkins is innocent.  The butler *didn't* do it! :-)

Comment: I installed using --enable-future-java command line flag but i do not have any plugins available in jenkins now @Michael

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run Jenkins on Java 11. [As you can see here, it is just experimentally supported.](https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/) To enable Jenkins run on Java 11 version you should add the --enable-future-java command line flag.